# Screen wide open, icons disappeared

Tags: keyboard, display, icons

I accidentally pressed multiple keys on my keyboard, and the screen opened wide. I was seeing just a strip of the icons, but now they've disappeared totally. Can you please guide me to fix this problem? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "screen opens wide" ? Maybe adding a screenshot will help.

Answer (score 1):

Did this happen while on a web browser? Do you maybe just need to press the fullscreen button (<kbd>F11</kbd>)?

(<kbd>F11</kbd> toggles fullscreen on/off, which hides/shows the taskbar and top bar).

Answer (score 0):

You probably zoomed the desktop with `Alt+scroll-up`. Do a `Alt+scroll-down`, with mouse or touch-pad (keep `Alt` pressed).